# Fix MBR after installing Windows on Linux partition

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, partition, windows

I have a server with two disks (each with a single `ext4` partition):

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0 223.6G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 223.6G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 223.6G  0 part /data
```

`sda` disk's partition has bootable Linux (Fedora).

I used WoeUSB to write a Windows Server 2016 ISO on `sdb`, as NTFS filesystem. I'm able to boot from it, run the Windows setup, remove & format the `sda` partition during the setup, and install Windows on `sda`.

But after the installation, booting from the `sda` disk (now with Windows) doesn't work. It shows an error:

```
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c:120:unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue > _
```

My guess is that the `sda` disk still has the old Linux MBR, due to which it doesn't boot.

How can I fix this so that Windows can boot from `sda`, and even better, replace grub altogether with Windows bootloader (which I assumed the Windows setup would do when I deleted its partition and formatted it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess about Linux MBR (or technically GRUB) on `sda` appears correct.

Boot from the Windows installation media, and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to get a Command Prompt, or select your language/keyboard preferences in the first screen, click `Next`, and then click `Repair your Computer`. From there you should gain access to a Command Prompt.

In Command Prompt, you can use `bootrec /fixmbr`.

Alternatively, find the drive letter associated with `sda` (I assume it will be C: here) and use:

```
 bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
```